# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost

Tags: eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

After moving to the osgi version org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633.jar,the following exception is thrown
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost

I use this class to check if a bundle is instance of BundleHost.

Comment: It no longer exists in current Eclipse releases. Since it was an internal class you should not have been using it. Why do you want to test if a bundle is an instance of BundleHost?

Comment: if (bundle instanceof BundleHost && ((BundleHost) bundle).getBundleData() instanceof BaseData) {
      file = ((BaseData) ((BundleHost) bundle).getBundleData()).getBundleFile().getBaseFile();
    }

Comment: What file did that return?

Comment: What is the thing you are really trying to do here? Perhaps there is a better solution that does not involve implementation specific types.